# Icon in jqxgrid Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jqxgrid

I am having hard time to implement icon in jqxgrid. Here is my code
https://jseditor.io/?key=gqgrid-angular

I am trying to show "Edit" and "Delete" icon instead of text / button. If i use following code, icon is displaying but its in box and no action is performing after clicking on it. If i use "return del" its performing action.

```
      {
    text: '', datafield: 'Delete',
    width: 33, columnType: 'button',
    cellsRenderer: (row: number, column: any, value: any, defaulthtml: string, columnproperties: any, rowdata: any) => {
       return '<i class="fa fa-trash deleteButton"></i>';
     // return 'del';
    },
    buttonClick: (row: number): void => {
        console.log("*********");
        this.deleteRow(row);
    }
  }
```

Please can you suggest what i am doing wrong? How i show icon and it perform action upon click.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your component

```
.jqx-grid-cell input[type='button'] {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.01 !important;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
  display: block !important;
}
```

For more info:

- Normally, with text, the column type `button` will render an `input` element.
- Whenever you have a `<` character in the cell (via cellsRenderer), such as `<img, <i`. It will try to render both input and image. To display the image, it will need to hide the input => the code make the input display: none.

What interesting is the code that attach click handler is still using `firstchild` selector, which will eventually apply to the invisible `input`.
All the logic above could be found in `jqxgrid.js: _renderbuttoncell` function.

Took me 2 hours to scrutinize the document and debug the issue. Then this answer came to me
https://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/jqxgrid-column-button-not-firing-event-after-adding-icon-over-there/

Comment: Thank you i tried still no effect. If possible can you show on jseditor?

Comment: try it on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ywpp3v?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Thanks but i am still unable to figure out issue in my code.

Comment: Here, in Stackoverflow, we don't do your homework https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions